# File Download, should PHP/MySQL handle it or let the Apache handle it?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

The issue I'm facing at the moment is I have a column in my MySQL database, the data in each row for that column remains static for the most part, unless an edit needs to happen, what I would like to know please is what would be the best course I should take to manage the content, should I give PHP the code (headers) to force the content to be downloadable (so the content remains in the MySQL database, (the content is just plain text), or should I have the content in files already on my server and just directly link to the files.

I've been working on a script so the content is editable from the browser (as a couple people plus myself will have access to the data), I'm just not sure if giving a directory (777) read write access is secure.

Thank you very much in advance to anyone who replies :)

Comment: This question would be best if you asked it on serverfault.com . This Question also needs to be a lot more clear so others can understand what you are asking. The question in its current state will not be accepted to stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you very much